# Twitter Bootstrap Button Active State

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, twitter-bootstrap, focus

I am almost exclusively using <a> tags with a class of "btn" for the buttons in my web app.

The problem is that when users use the <tab> key to navigate form fields, there is no way to identify when one of these "buttons" has the focus, which is frustrating them.

I tried adding this to the CSS:

a.btn:active{background-color:red;}

But that doesn't really do what I want; That only changes the background color *while* the button is being clicked. It doesn't affect how the button appears when the button receives the focus via the <tab> key.

I also tried using :focus instead of :active, but that doesn't really work either.

Does anyone know of a way I could globally change this in my app?

Comment: What are the results when using `:active` and `:focus`? Could we see an example?

Comment: Why don't you use the tag button?

Comment: I'm not sure how you code looks, but `:focus` is the CSS property you're looking for

Comment: By default BS do style the `:focus` state (bootstrap.css:2978): `.btn:focus {
  outline: thin dotted #333;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:focus` is the way to go. Maybe Twitter bootstrap is overriding your `:focus` styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/4aVuK/2/

Maybe try to add !important in your css.

```
a.btn:focus{background-color:red !important;}
```

Comment: `!important` is your friend with Twitter Bootstrap.